# About International Mathematics Competition (IMC)

Tags: contest-math

Can someone suggest me a book (or books), to practice for International Mathematics Competition (IMC)?
Also, how much does the participation to IMC cost?

Comment: Are you talking about this competiton  http://www.chiuchang.org/en_US/ ? If so, it's by invitation only.

Comment: OP might mean http://www.imc-math.org.uk/.

Comment: No my friend. I'm talking about http://www.imc-math.org.uk/ . I didn't know that there is another competition with the same name.

Comment: If you google "IMC", http://www.imc-math.org.uk/ should be the only math competition in the first google page.